# DataNucleus Class not Persistable Exception

Tags: java, netbeans, jdo, datanucleus

I was trying to made some basic persistent classes with datanucleus jdo(and neodatis as datastore).

I have the following three classes(copied fom the tutorial)

inventory.java

```
@PersistenceCapable
public class Inventory {

@PrimaryKey
String name = null;

Set<Product> products = new HashSet();

public Inventory(String name)
{
    this.name = name;}

public Set<Product> getProducts() {return products;}
}
```

Product.java

```
@PersistenceCapable
public class Product {

@PrimaryKey
@Persistent(valueStrategy=IdGeneratorStrategy.INCREMENT)
long id;
String name = null;
String description = null;
double price = 0.0;

public Product(String name, String desc, double price)
    {
    this.name = name;
    this.description = desc;
    this.price = price;}

}
```

and book.java

```
@PersistenceCapable
public class Book extends Product {

String author=null;
String isbn=null;
String publisher=null;

public Book(String name, String desc, double price, String author, 
            String isbn, String publisher)
{
    super(name,desc,price);
    this.author = author;
    this.isbn = isbn;
    this.publisher = publisher;
}    
}
```

all of them should have been correctly enhanched since when building the project i get this:

```
(...)
gen 31, 2013 12:10:14 AM org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer main
INFO: DataNucleus Enhancer (version 3.2.0.m2) for API "JDO" using JRE "1.7"
ENHANCED (PersistenceCapable) : minchiabbasta.Book
ENHANCED (PersistenceCapable) : minchiabbasta.Inventory
ENHANCED (PersistenceCapable) : minchiabbasta.Product
(...)
```

BUT

when running the application the Persistence manager fire up nicely, but when it try to make something persistent this exception get thrown

```
org.datanucleus.api.jdo.exceptions.ClassNotPersistenceCapableException: The class 
"minchiabbasta.Inventory" is not persistable. This means that it either hasnt been 
enhanced, or that the enhanced version of the file is not in the CLASSPATH (or is 
hidden by an unenhanced version), or the Meta-Data/annotations for the class are not 
found.
```

I can't manage to figure out why, can someone give me a hint?

Comment: The message lists 3 reasons that are possible, so check those 3 things.

Comment: @DataNucleus I am not _so_ stupid, of course i have checked those 3 things, specifically
1. the class has not been enhanched: the enhangher log say otherwise
2. the enhanched class is hidden: there is only one version of the class in the jar, and it's the enhanched one(the one the enhancher write).
3. the annotations are not found: just look the source file, the annotations are where they are supposed to be.

yet it give me that error...

Comment: Who referred to "stupidity" ? I suggested you look at those 3 things since those are the three most common things causing this. The enhancer enhances classes yes, but are the enhanced ones in the CLASSPATH at runtime? A bytecode decompiler would confirm if that class is enhanced, as would running "javap" on the class in question. You can also easily enough print out the stack trace of that exception. That gives the point in the source where the error comes from, and consequently why the class is considered not persistable; you haven't provided that.

Comment: The (freely downloadable) DataNucleus tutorial provides build files for Ant and Maven that work too, and you could easily enough start with those if having problems, to isolate where the problem is

Comment: Noone actually, i jumped the gun there, sorry.
However i've run javap on the Inventory class:
    Compiled from "Inventory.java"
    public class minchiabbasta.Inventory {
  java.lang.String name;
  java.util.Set<minchiabbasta.Product> products;
  public minchiabbasta.Inventory(java.lang.String);
  public java.util.Set<minchiabbasta.Product> getProducts();
    }

and seems like there's nothing more than the plain class... Strange, since it's the very file that the enhancher wrote...

Answer (score 0):

Years later, same symptom. In my case I got the same error and 3 suggestions on the stack trace. However for me the actual problem was none of those, but that I was running in Eclipse and on the Google | App Engine settings had not checked both "Enable local HRD support" and "User Datanucleous JDO/JPA to access the datastore". Once I checked those items I was able to persist using the same code as before, and did not get the above error.

Answer (score 0):

If your enhancer runs upon saving files in Eclipse, take notice to see if it enhances in the Eclipse console. I notice that my install of Eclipse forgets to enhance classes every once in a while. If it forgets, it will deploy the class to GAE not enhanced. Simply restarting Eclipse does the trick.

Answer (score -1):

try it:

```
@Entity // use this annotation 
public class MyClass
{
@Id
long id;

@Basic
@Convert(converter=URLStringConverter.class)
URL url;
```

Comment: hmm "entity" seem more JPA style... however it doesn't work at all.

Comment: datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform/ **JPA** /annotations.html
i am using the JDO api, not the JPA...